# Regex in Javascript for csv kind of string matching

Tags: javascript, regex, backtracking

I have a requirement to validate input using regex .
Requirement is to match the string in form of tuples(a,b,c) or more than 3 (a,b,c,d,e) but white space can occur before/after string boundaries
like below:

```
t1
t2,t1
 t1 , t2 
 a    
 a,b
```

Following are invalid

```
a,
,
<empty>
```

I came with this regex:

```
(\s*(\w+\s*,\s*)*\s*\w+\s*)
```

The matching works fine but it has [polynomial complexity](https://devina.io/redos-checker)  for Attack string '\t'.repeat(1651) + '\t'.repeat(1651) + ',0'

I consider input as matching if the main group equals to input string. I mean I would reject inputs like a, although it matched subgroup.

Any suggestions to make it safe/linear. tried lookahead approach and lazy quantifiers but could not get it right?

Once I make this safe expression, end goal is to add a prefix/suffix and make it safe

something like

```js
    PREFIX (\s*(\w+\s*,\s*)*\s*\w+\s*) SUFFIX
```

I was trying something like this but it stops matching correct inputs

PREFIX(?=(?(\s*(\w+\s*,\s*)*\s*\w+\s*)))\k SUFFIX)

With above even correct inputs like below are also not matched

```
PREFIX a,b SUFFIX
```

Thanks..

Comment: Couldn't you just trim the string before testing with regex?

Comment: Yes this would make regex expression simple too. I was trying to fix the regex so that it works with all kinds of inputs where we could miss in trim/pre-process phase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update the pattern by starting to match 1+ word characters, and then optionally repeat a comma between optional whitespace chars and then 1+ word characters.

Note that using `\s` can also match newlines.

```
PREFIX \w+(?:\s*,\s*\w+)* SUFFIX
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked perfectly. Can it be modified to handle multi-byte chars like  "PREFIX idéd,b SUFFIX" . I tried something like this "PREFIX(\w|[^\x20-\x7F])+(?:\s*,\s*(\w|[^\x20-\x7F])+)*SUFFIX" . It goes to exponential complexity :(

Comment: @PavanKumar Try it like this without the alternation `|` like `PREFIX [^,\s]+(?:[ \t]*,[ \t]*[^,\s]+)* SUFFIX` See https://regex101.com/r/A9ZclQ/1

Comment: great :) Thanks for the quick response. very simple to understand the regex expression too..

Comment: I just wanted to allow 0 spaces for prefix/suffix and changed to this "PREFIX\s*[^,\s]+(?:[ \t]*,[ \t]*[^,\s]+)*\s*SUFFIX". It then becomes polynomial complexity . any easier fix or I just have to replace PREFIX with PREFIX\s and SUFFIX with \sSUFFIX

Comment: @PavanKumar You could bypass that check using lookaheads with capture groups as there is no backtracking in a lookahead `\bPREFIX(?=([ \t]*))\1[^,\s]+(?=((?:[ \t]*,[ \t]*[^,\s]+)*[\t ]*SUFFIX\b))\2` https://regex101.com/r/V6XRGV/1

Comment: any idea for certain inputs in php, python this comes as catastrophic. For JS  it comes as no match properly..  https://regex101.com/r/a1pFWz/1

Comment: @PavanKumar Try using word boundaries https://regex101.com/r/reLONb/1 or in php you can use possessive quantifiers and an atomic group https://regex101.com/r/W3pc2b/1

Comment: Thanks for details and sharing the pointers . https://regex101.com/r/reLONb/1 is reported as polynomial by the [tool](https://devina.io/redos-checker) . As I increase the attack string length, it takes longer time ...

Comment: @PavanKumar And if you put the whole first part except PREFIX in group 1? https://regex101.com/r/7A4wG7/1

Comment: simulated here for php https://regex101.com/r/ZQf9IA/1.  Thanks...

Comment: @PavanKumar It takes longer, but the string is also very long https://regex101.com/r/DTOCDT/1 Where are you using the regex for? Can you also use code to do some prevalidations?

Comment: Yes I do some validation on max length before regex processing. So it could be an non-issue.   Just trying to see if we can even make report as safe from tool aswell.     The above one you modified was safe but it rejects valid input PREFIX(id)SUFFIX . Not a critical though..

Comment: @PavanKumar A great that you can do some preprocessing before firing the regex. Let me know if you need some more assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the simplest solution:

```
(\s*\w+\s*,?)*
```

The pattern is: any whitespace, followed by one or more words, followed by any whitespace, followed by one or zero commas. The pattern may appear 0 or many times.

That site says this is linear and safe.

This will do the same thing as the regex you provided, except that it allows a trailing comma and also matches the empty string.

If that doesn't do what you need, then please provide a more detailed description and more examples of what should pass or fail validation.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I clarified my requirements with more data. Please see.